# dll: timer not firing

Tags: c#, dll, timer

I have a dll that has a timer control in it, inside I have a message box. The timer has been enabled and the interval has been set to 100 seconds, but for some reason it's not firing. I added button to check if it's enabled, and timer1.enabled property is set to true, but it doesn't fire even once. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks!

Dll Code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

This is how I call the dll form:

```
    M.ModuleInterface module = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as M.ModuleInterface;
    Thread t = new Thread(module.showForm);
    t.Start();
```

showForm Method:

```
    void M.ModuleInterface.showForm()
    {
        log("GUI::Initialized()");
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Is it winform timer and you're in Console App?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's an winform application

Comment: share your code please

Comment: If the DLL is also a project in your solution which you reference from your application, you could set a breakpoint and see whether the event actually gets called.

Comment: I have a message box inside the timer and log, the timer doesn't get triggered

Comment: who is registered to  timer1_Tick and when?

Answer (score 1):

i believe, judging by your words alone, that you simply forgot to register to the time.

do:

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
  }

  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // Your code here
  }
```

this little example works just fine:

```
  private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     timer1.Interval = 100;
     this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
     timer1.Enabled = true;
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // timer is triggered. code here is called
  }
```

Comment: I did as you said, but it is still not triggering, I don't understand why.. it was also registered in my Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: @user2320462 hmm... take the second example i gave and check it. if that not triggered then you'll have to provide more information as who open the form and are you sure the form is opened

Comment: i tried the second example and it still is not triggering, I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Any other tips? Thanks

Comment: @user2320462 create a new project. the example i gave you works, so the only reason it won't work is the entire solution has been created/built wrong.